# Class 'ng-invalid-required' added correctly but not removed when it should be removed

Tags: angularjs, styles, required

I am using `$watch()` to control the `required` attribute using the following custom directive:

```
app.directive('checkIfRequired', ['$compile', '$timeout', '$parse', function ($compile, $timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        /*require: '?ngModel',*/
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            var children = $(":input", el);
            var saveIsValidationRequired;
            //Run the following as early as possible but just wait (using promise) until 
            //  the list of required fields is retrieved from Database
            scope.requiredFieldsPromise.then(function(success) {
                //If needed, stop validation while adding required attribute
                saveIsValidationRequired = scope.isValidationRequired;  //Save current flag value
                scope.stopExecValidations();
                //remove the attribute `check-if-required` to avoid recursive calls
                el.removeAttr('check-if-required');
                angular.forEach(children, function(value, key) {
                    if (scope.isFieldRequired(value.id)) {
                        angular.element(value).attr('required', true);
                        $compile(value)(scope);
                    }
                    //Check if the element is not in "Required" list, and it has a function to control requried, then
                    //... execute the function using $watch and $parse and add the required attribute accordingly 
                    if (!angular.element(value).prop('required') && value.attributes.hasOwnProperty("check-if-required-expr")) {
                        var isRequiredExpr = value.attributes["check-if-required-expr"].value;
                        scope.$watch(function (){
                                var exprValue = $parse(isRequiredExpr)(scope);
                                return exprValue;
                            }
                            , function (oldValue, newValue){
                                var isRequired = $parse(isRequiredExpr)(scope);
                                if (isRequired) {
                                    angular.element(value).prop('required', true);
                                    $compile(value)(scope);
                                } else {
                                    angular.element(value).prop('required', false);
                                    $compile(value)(scope);
                                }
                                var elModel = angular.element(value).controller("ngModel");
                                elModel.$setViewValue(elModel.$viewValue);
                            })
                    }
                });
                //If saved flag value is true, enable validation
                if (saveIsValidationRequired) {
                    scope.startExecValidations();
                }
            })
            //})
        }
    };
}]);
```

Basically, the above directive checks if any if the child elements is required, then it will add the required attribute using `$compile(value)(scope)`, if not, then it will check if `check-if-required-expr` expression is specified, if yes, it will use `$watch()` to evaluate the expression, and set the required attribute accordingly.

See image below for more details.

All is working fine. The only problem is that when the "Name" field is cleared, the required attribute for "Member #" field should be removed, and the highlight should be cleared, however, the class `ng-invalid-required` is still added and this is causing the highlight to be there.

You can see the the `$error` object for the `NgModelController` named `super_aic_member_number` is calculated correctly as per the intended logic.

So basically the question here is how to ensure the style is synchronized correctly with the change of the `required` attribute?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to find the solution. Instead of using `$watch()` to monitor the expression `check-if-required-expr`, I am simply now adding this expression to the `ng-required` attribute, then, I will compile.

So far, it is working fine.

Here is the updated code:

```
app.directive('checkIfRequired', ['$compile', '$timeout', '$parse', function ($compile, $timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        /*require: '?ngModel',*/
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            /*if (!ngModel) {
                return;
            }*/
            //debugger;
            var children = $(":input", el);
            var saveIsValidationRequired;
            //Run the following as early as possible but just wait (using promise) until 
            //  the list of required fields is retrieved from Database
            scope.requiredFieldsPromise.then(function(success) {
                //If needed, stop validation while adding required attribute
                saveIsValidationRequired = scope.isValidationRequired;  //Save current flag value
                scope.stopExecValidations();
                //remove the attribute `check-if-required` to avoid recursive calls
                el.removeAttr('check-if-required');
                angular.forEach(children, function(value, key) {
                    //debugger;  && (value.id != "pi_subject_namex" && value.id != "pi_subj_provincex")
                    if (scope.isFieldRequired(value.id)) {
                        angular.element(value).attr('required', true);
                        //el.removeAttr('check-if-required');
                        $compile(value)(scope);
                    }
                    //Check if the element is not in "Required" list, and it has an expression to control requried, then
                    //... add the attribute 'ng-required' with the expression specified to the element and compile.
                    if (!angular.element(value).prop('required') && value.attributes.hasOwnProperty("check-if-required-expr")) {
                        var isRequiredExpr = value.attributes["check-if-required-expr"].value;
                        angular.element(value).attr('ng-required', isRequiredExpr);
                        $compile(value)(scope);
                    }
                });
                //If saved flag value is ture, enable validation
                if (saveIsValidationRequired) {
                    scope.startExecValidations();
                }
            })
            //})
        }
    };
}]);
```